# ComboBox in DataGridView WinForm not rendering selected value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have a weird problem with ComboBox Column in DataGridView in WinForm.

When I select the item from ComboBox, the selected value would not be rendered by the ComboBox. I need to click the ComboBox so that the selected value of the ComboBox would be rendered or displayed. If not, the ComboBox would just display empty.

The weird thing is this only happen in my first ComboBox Column in DataGridView.

In other words, this issue is not happening with my Second, Third or etc ComboBox Column in DataGridView.

Any ideas? Could it be a DataGridView bugs?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: As always, post code that duplicates the problem for us.

Comment: Do you create the comboboxes in code?

Comment: Yes. I created the comboboxes in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your attention.

I manage to find the solution for the question that I have asked.

**Overview:**

> 1. I populate rows in `DataGridView` manually by adding row into `DataGridView`.
> 2. For `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` object, I use `DataSource` to populate the Items instead of adding the Items manually to the
>      ComboBoxCell.

**The Problem:**

Whenever you select the item in ComboBox, it is unable to render the selected value in the ComboBox. It would only show the value if you click it.

Solution:
It turns out in the code somewhere after I set the `DataSource` of the `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`, I called its method, `DataGridViewComboBoxCell.Items.Count`. This is the source of the weird behaviour.

**Somehow, if you have set the ComboBoxCell DataSource, and you call Items.Count method, it would show that weird behaviour.**

I should not use `Items.Count` since I am using DataSource. The Items.Count would always be zero because the DataBinding it's not happened instantly the moment you set the DataSource.

Hopefully this post would help someone else in the future. Thanks.